# How to run "Source file.sql" command from MySQL CLI in the background?

Tags: command-line, mysql, background-process, nohup

I am currently on Ubuntu 22.04. I have over 30 SQL files that creates new databases and some of them are over 10 GB.
I don't want to import those files into MySQL using `MySQL < File.sql`, because using this method I will have to create the databases manually first.

With the `Source File.sql` command the databases will be created from the query.
But, I am connected on the server using a VPN, and my network is kinda messed up at the moment.

How do I run this command and throw it to the background?
I know how to send a app to the background using `nohup`, but I do not know how to send a MySQL query to the background using `nohup`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command `screen` which allows you to launch a command in a detached session.

1. Install `screen` with the command:

   ```
   sudo apt install screen
   ```
2. Launch your command in a detached screen:

   ```
   screen -dmS "screenNameHere" your command here
   ```
3. In order to see your commands progress or result, you can reattach that session with the command:

   ```
   screen -r screenNameHere
   ```

More info on the `screen` command [here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/screen).